# in what ways will an event ever need to be set to *capturing*?

Tags: javascript, html, dhtml

After reading this page http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html, I can't help but say that Microsoft had really gotten the things right when they decided to do bubbling because capturing is just.. *unintuitive*

hence this question: in what ways will an event ever need to be set to *capturing* ? or simply in all the projects you've done, when have you ever *required* an event to be capturing?

Comment: The biggest reason not to use it is lack of support in old IE's. 
It is about the only way to catch non-bubbling events by a parent. And it would make delegating events to a parent simpler.

Answer (score 1):

What Kennebec alluded to in the comments is correct.  There are events (`focus`, `blur`) which simply do not bubble, but they will still capture.  This allows one to still use event delegation with those events.  Event delegation using bubbling/capturing is often times cleaner and more efficient.

Here is a good article from Quirks explaining event capturing and why it makes sense when using events like `focus` and `blur`:
http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2008/04/delegating_the.html

In my projects, I haven't run into a situation where event capturing was required.  However in many places where I've used event bubbling I could have used event capturing instead.